# Using Python Bisect on List of Lists Throw Error

Tags: python, bisect

I am trying to use Bisect to find where I should insert a new element.

The list to search is a list of lists. The inner list has two elements and I want to compare using the first element.

In the bisect function [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect), it says that the key function is supposed to take the element and get the value to compare. In this case, I am getting the first element of the list.

```
i = bisect.bisect([[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]], 4, lambda x: x[0])
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'function' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I also tried to warp the item with a list but the problem persists

```
i = bisect.bisect([[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]], [4,5] , lambda x: x[0])
```

If I tried to remove the key function, it works if I warp the value by a list:

```
i = bisect.bisect([[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]], [4])
print(i)
> 3
```

However, I am still not sure why the key function is not working.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The key function must be passed as a named argument `key=...`.  Otherwise it is treated as just another data argument.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the link you provided, the third argument of `bisect` is the left side of the search scope, not the key:

```
bisect.bisect(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, *, key=None)
```

To use key, use the keyword argument:

```
>>> bisect.bisect([[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]], 4, key=lambda x: x[0])
3
```